# Using async await to run SQL Server stored procedure in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, sql-server, node-mssql

I am new to using SQL Server with nodejs. I am using the `node-mssql` library. I am finding stored procedure to be a bit challenging.

My stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_addStudent] 
    @StudentID int, 
    @StudentName varchar(50), 
    @TimeStamp datetime, 
    @Notes varchar(MAX) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO Students (StudentID , StudentName , [TimeStamp], Notes) 
    VALUES (@StudentID , @StudentName , @TimeStamp, @Notes); 
END
```

I found out a way to execute this stored procedure without parameters online using try catch:

```
async function getDataFromProcedure(dbConfig, procedureName) {
  try {
    await sql.connect(dbConfig);
    const request = new sql.Request();
    recordsets = await request.execute(procedureName);
    return recordsets[0];
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error here
  }
};
```

How do I add parameters to the stored procedure using try catch?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at [the documentation](https://tediousjs.github.io/node-mssql/#execute-procedure-callback) shows how to add input/output parameters.  For example:

```
const request = new sql.Request();
request.input('input_parameter', sql.Int, value);
request.output('output_parameter', sql.Int);
const result = await request.execute(procedureName);
```

This would include a variables called `value` as an input parameter called `input_parameter`, and also set up an expected output parameter called `output_parameter` (it's assumed here that they're both already defined in the stored procedure).  The output parameter could later be observed in `result.output`.